# Use a bash file to loop over other bash files with different paramer values

Tags: bash, shell, command-line

I have a shell file *script.sh* with the following commands:

```
#!/bin/sh
#SBATCH --partition=univ2       
#SBATCH --nodes=2               
#SBATCH --ntasks-per-node=13    
mpirun -n 25 benchmark.out $param
```

where *param* is an integer from the set {1,2,...,10}. Here *param* is a command line argument that is passed over to the executable benchmark.out. I want to create another shell file *master.sh* (in the same directory as *script.sh*) which would contain a loop over *param* (from 1 to 10), such that upon each iteration, *script.sh* is executed with a given value of *param*. How should this file look like? Thank you.

Comment: Is there a reason you're specifying it as `$param` rather than `"$1"`? I mean, we *can* work with that (by passing the variable through the environment), but it's not a usual approach.

Comment: Also, `#!/bin/sh` makes this a `sh` script, not a `bash` script. Please tag accordingly. (POSIX sh is a considerably more limited language than bash).

Answer (score 1):

Master

```
#!/bin/bash

for param in `seq 1 1 10`; do
  ./script.sh $param
done
```

Script

```
#!/bin/sh
#SBATCH --partition=univ2       
#SBATCH --nodes=2               
#SBATCH --ntasks-per-node=13    
mpirun -n 25 benchmark.out $1
```

Comment: By way of showcasing best practices, consider `"$1"` and `"$param"` rather than bare `$i` and `$param`. Also, `seq` is not a POSIX-standardized command, so it's not guaranteed to be available.

Comment: The POSIX-compliant way to count is `i=1; while [ "$i" -le 10 ]; do ...; i=$((i + 1)); done`, whereas the bash way is `for ((i=1; i<=10; i++)); do ...; done` -- neither of these require `seq`.